# During the update it increments a new data Springboot java

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm training with springboot,h2 hibernate, tried to do a full crud. Everything works except that when I modify a data, it modifies the selected data but it adds one more to my list. Who can tell me what is wrong with my code? thanks in advance.

controller:

```
@PutMapping("/updateMovie/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity updateMovie(@PathVariable Long id, @RequestBody Movie movie){
        
        return ResponseEntity.ok(movieService.updateMovie(id, movie));
    }
```

Service

```
public Movie updateMovie(@PathVariable Long id, @RequestBody Movie movie){

        Movie currentMovie = movieRepository.findById(id).orElseThrow(RuntimeException::new);
        currentMovie.setTitle(movie.getTitle());
        currentMovie.setDescription(movie.getDescription());
        currentMovie.setDuration(movie.getDuration());
       
        return movieRepository.save(movie);
    }
```

Model

```
public class Movie {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name= "title")
    private String title;

    @NonNull
    @Column(name= "duration")
    private Integer duration;

    @Column(name= "description")
    private String description;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a bug in your code. Instead of updating the existing record, you just save the inputed movie object, which will result in creating a new row in the db.

Should be `return movieRepository.save(currentMovie);`

Comment: Thank you very much @tbjorch, that's the error, everything works

Comment: Take care of your variables and check twice if you use them correctly ;) you are not alone to make these kind of error. You can check with the debugger to see with var is used in step by step mode, in case of these kind of "bug".